# Multiply string and integer columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with such a structure[1] and i want to multiply the string and integer columns.

```
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+--+
| url                  | date       | word                    | mentioned |  |
|----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+--+
| newspaperarticle.com | 2018-12-22 | [canada,house,micheal]  | [2,2,1]   |  |
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 | [new york,murder,angry] | [2,3,1]   |  |
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+-
```

And I want the multiplied number of words in the column name

```
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------+---+--+
| url                  | date       | word                            |mentioned 
|----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------+---+--+
| newspaperarticle.com | 2018-12-22 | [canada,canada,house,..]        |[2,2,1]     
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 | [new york,new york,murder,..]   |[2,3,1]   
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-------+---+--+
```

What i did so far was multiplying the columns with the multiply method that didnt work. I also tried it with for loops with indexing the single elements and multiplying them but always go the error string out of index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and use [`series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) , the  aggregate as list on level=0:

```
s = [df[i].explode() for i in ['word','mentioned']]
df['word'] = s[0].repeat(s[1]).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

---

```
print(df)

                    url        date  \
0  newspaperarticle.com  2018-12-22   
1        articleUSA.com  2018-12-23   

                                                word  mentioned  
0            [canada, canada, house, house, micheal]  [2, 2, 1]  
1  [new york, new york, murder, murder, murder, a...  [2, 3, 1]
```

**Note:** This is assuming that `word` and `mentioned` columns are series of lists and not string representation of lists.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` will fail on string `[canada,canada,house]` due to lack of string delimiters. I sincerely hope those **are** lists.

Comment: @Błotosmętek you are right  , removed that note, then we have to manipulate the input data . I hope so too :)

Comment: No worries, those are lists, thanks never heard of the repeat function its much easier this way then doing multiple for loops and working around the indexes :)